# Array counfusion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this below array as a string.
11=>A=>Attempt, 12=>B=>Skip, 13=>A=>Attempt, 14=>A=>Skip, 15=>B=>Skip, 16=>A=>Skip
But i wan the first key(12) which is skip if user perform an action its value will change then it should return next key(14) which is again skip.
I have tried;

```
        //Converting to array
        for($i=0;$i<count($aa);$i++) {
            $x=explode('=>',$aa[$i]);
            $total_answer[$x[0]] = array($x[1],$x[2]);
          }
          // Matchhing option and question
          foreach($total_answer as $key=>$value)
          {
                  if($name=='Skip' || $name=="None")
                 {
                    $total_answer[$key][1]=$name;                 
              }
          }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Is it possible that you just mixed up `$name` and `$value` in your if-clause?

Comment: This is quite unclear. What is the desired format of the final array?

Comment: This is too unclear. Try providing examples that show what your input is and what your expected output would be.

Answer (score 0):

i see you have `$name` variable, but none of your array sign to `name` var,

```
$str="11=>A=>Attempt, 12=>B=>Skip, 13=>A=>Attempt, 14=>A=>Skip, 15=>B=>Skip, 16=>A=>Skip";

//first we need to separate from ,
$arr=explode(',',$str);

//initiate new array
$total_answer=[];

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    //dont forget to trim out space
    $x=explode('=>',trim($arr[$i]));
    $total_answer[$x[0]]= array($x[1],$x[2]);
}


foreach($total_answer as $key=>$value)
{
    //from where this $name variable come from?
    if($name=='Skip' || $name=="None")
    {
        $total_answer[$key][1]=$name;                 
    }
}
```

and i confused with your statement

> But i wan the first key(12) which is skip if user perform an action
>   its value will change then it should return next key(14) which is
>   again skip. I have tried;

please put your output goal.